# procedural generation of a lesion

Tags: procedural

How would you approach procedural generation of objects that look like this:

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Comment: You don't give many details, but i would go for Particles + Metaballs. (Metaballs for sure, Particles depending of what you're trying to achieve)

Comment: @thibsert thank you! Do you think that NURBS can also be used? about details - I am procedurally generating lesions for a medical purpose - either benign or cancer, it is not for "artistic" reasons. I don't know what else to say apart from the example images and that I need to be able to randomly generate the way they look like they've "grown". However, being able to generate them randomly in a way similar to the images I've embeddeding the post is good enough for now. Any guiding questions are very welcome :)

Comment: I don't see how NURBS would help but maybe I miss something. I'll try to obtain something similar to your examples and post a more elaborate answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need them to "look like they've grown", but you don't need to animate the growing (or show various steps of the growing), is that right ?

Comment: That is correct, I do not need to animate them or show steps of the growing. Thanks :)